# DateTime.Now accounts for DST

Tags: c#, datetime, dst

My DateTime object is assigned the local time using DateTime.Now. I wanted to know if this object will give the correct current local time once Daylight time begins/ends. Or do I need a workaround?

Comment: As long as by "local" you realize this is the local time zone of the machine that the code is running at, then mservidio's answer is correct.  In other words, this is fine for a desktop app.  But *not* for a web application - since that would be the *server's* local time.

Comment: Correct! I didn't think of it in that angle. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) is based on the local machine time.

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the local time.

Comment: How does this property fetch the local time? From the system? Is that why it accounts for dst because the system time does?

Comment: Yes, correct. If you do not want to be affected by DST, you could use UTC time instead.

Comment: include Matt's comment in your answer lest someone else should try it and bring down his web application :)

Comment: @TylerDurden - It's a common mistake, but mservidio's answer is perfectly accurate.

Comment: I would argue that `DateTime.Now` **only** accounts for DST if your system has `Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Savings Time` checked under the time zone settings. So, it would be true for a *very high percentage* of cases. However, it's *very much environment based.*

Comment: @neoistheone - Valid point. In the case of the question, it was phrased with the given that DST will happen (begin/end).